# Can i put a box in half over another box (without px)?

Tags: html, css, containers, position, absolute

Is there an optimal solution for my problem? I have a green box with position: relative; and a white box with position: absolute;

**The absolute box has top: 0; I only wish that the white box is exactly centered (with one half over the green box and the other half outside). Is there a solution for this in CSS, regardless of the height of the box in px?**

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate is your friend:

```
.white-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Simple and helpful, thank you very much! :)